# Rotating a square in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

With PIL, I want to draw a rotated square on an image, by specifying the square side length, and the rotation angle. The square should be white, and the background grey. For example, the following image has a rotation of 45 degrees:

[image]

The only way I know how to do rotations in PIL is by rotating the entire image. But if I start with the following image:

[image]

And then rotate it by 45 degrees, I get this:

[image]

That method just introduces black parts to fill in the "undefined" region of the image.

How can I rotate just the square?

The code to generate my original square (the second figure) is as follows:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.new('L', (100, 100), 127)
pixels = image.load()

for i in range(30, image.size[0] - 30):
    for j in range(30, image.size[1] - 30):
        pixels[i, j] = 255

rotated_image = image.rotate(45)
rotated_image.save("rotated_image.bmp")
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. A "before" and "after" image might be useful here.

Comment: I've now updated the question accordingly!

Comment: Possible duplicate (or at least this looks to answer the question) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252170/specify-image-filling-color-when-rotating-in-python-with-pil-and-setting-expand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you want to do is draw a solid color square at some arbitrary angle, you can use trigonometry to calculate the vertices of the rotated square, then draw it with `polygon`.

```
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

#finds the straight-line distance between two points
def distance(ax, ay, bx, by):
    return math.sqrt((by - ay)**2 + (bx - ax)**2)

#rotates point `A` about point `B` by `angle` radians clockwise.
def rotated_about(ax, ay, bx, by, angle):
    radius = distance(ax,ay,bx,by)
    angle += math.atan2(ay-by, ax-bx)
    return (
        round(bx + radius * math.cos(angle)),
        round(by + radius * math.sin(angle))
    )

image = Image.new('L', (100, 100), 127)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

square_center = (50,50)
square_length = 40

square_vertices = (
    (square_center[0] + square_length / 2, square_center[1] + square_length / 2),
    (square_center[0] + square_length / 2, square_center[1] - square_length / 2),
    (square_center[0] - square_length / 2, square_center[1] - square_length / 2),
    (square_center[0] - square_length / 2, square_center[1] + square_length / 2)
)

square_vertices = [rotated_about(x,y, square_center[0], square_center[1], math.radians(45)) for x,y in square_vertices]

draw.polygon(square_vertices, fill=255)

image.save("output.png")
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's generalize to a rectangle:

- length **l** in x and width **w** in y.
- using a "rotation matrix".

Rotation code:

```
import math

def makeRectangle(l, w, theta, offset=(0,0)):
    c, s = math.cos(theta), math.sin(theta)
    rectCoords = [(l/2.0, w/2.0), (l/2.0, -w/2.0), (-l/2.0, -w/2.0), (-l/2.0, w/2.0)]
    return [(c*x-s*y+offset[0], s*x+c*y+offset[1]) for (x,y) in rectCoords]
```

Drawing code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
import math

L=512; W=512
image = Image.new("1", (L, W))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

vertices = makeRectangle(100, 200, 45*math.pi/180, offset=(L/2, W/2))
draw.polygon(vertices, fill=1)

image.save("test.png")
```