# What should getBoundingClientRect() on a transformed SVG element return?

Tags: javascript, svg, specifications

Today I tested what happens when you use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-getclientrects-and-getboundingclientrect-methods) on an SVG element that has been rotated.

#### Test: http://phrogz.net/svg/getBoundingClientRect-on-rotated-elements.html

The result is that:

- Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE appear to calculate the local (untransformed) bounding box of the element, and then return the client rect *for that bounding box*. This can result in a client rect larger than seems appropriate.
- Firefox, on the other hand, clips the client rect to fit the element itself.

[image: Visual appearance of the two cases;]

Which behavior is correct according to the specifications?

*For what it's worth, I [prefer the Firefox behavior](http://phrogz.net/getboundingclientrect-is-lame-for-svg), but (absent understanding the specs) **think** that Firefox's deviation should be [considered a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755947).*

Comment: With FF34 it's OK, but not on Safari 8 (desktop and mobile) (and it's worst!)

Answer (score 3):

Non-firefox browsers don't seem to give useful results and don't seem to match the relevant specifications either.

The [CSSOM View Module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#the-getclientrects-and-getboundingclientrect-methods) delegates to the SVG specification which says it's the [tight bounding box after transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) not the tight bounding box transformed so I maintain that I implemented it correctly.

Comment: I agree about the "useful results" comment...but when has that ever stood in the way of following specs? (_cough_ defaulting to `boz-sizing:content-box` _cough_) Disregarding specs and doing what is more 'useful' is what IE4-6 did, so let's not focus the discussion on that when determining whether the current behavior is correct. (It is an excellent argument, however, for revising the CSSOM working draft.)

Comment: The definition of "bounding box" in the SVG 1.1 specs occurs in section 7.11 and says: _"The bounding box is the tightest fitting rectangle **aligned with the axes of the applicable element's user coordinate system** that entirely encloses the applicable element and its descendants. The bounding box is computed exclusive of any values for clipping, masking, filter effects, opacity and stroke-width."_ By the letter of the law (and the fact that a clientRect cannot represent four non-axis-aligned points) it seems to me that unless the specifications are changed, Firefox is currently wrong.

Comment: I think the CSSOM specification should change as that's not very useful for GetBoundingClientRect. I think Firefox will be sticking with its current implementation.

Comment: So what happens if you take a square html div, make it into a circle by using border-radius and then rotate it with a CSS transform? Is the bounding box big or correct?

Comment: I note that the current version of Firefox (v26) now behaves the same as the others (the "too big" bounding box). I'm interested to know why it changed.

Comment: Inadvertently I imagine. Raise a bug in bugzilla and cc me as I thought we had regression tests for this.

Comment: Absolutely agree that Firefox is the more useful here. I've found SVG support in Firefox is generally just better than the rest of the browsers - despite it not being my browser of choice.