# Why are my images not being cropped appropriately?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have a data set of different images. After drawing ellipses, I want to crop them.

[image]

I drew ellipses on them. The actual ellipses are the blue ones. The green ones are just how they look like with their angle 0 degrees.

[image]

I am using numpy array slicing to get the cropped image:

```
output_image[y-(minor_axis/2):y+(minor_axis/2), x-(major_axis/2):x+(major_axis/2)]
```

However the result isn't as it should be. For example the result of the large ellipse looking like an oval is as follows:

[image]

I first thought that it is happening because I am using angle during numpy slicing. Therefore, I drew the green circles of angle 0 degree having the same other major axis, minor axis etc values but the result also doesn't correspond to the green circle.

What's going on here?

Comment: Get the `boundingRect` of the `RotatedRect` representing the ellipse.

Comment: bit hard to tell without seeing your code

Comment: It actually is, You are croping the bounding box of the big blue ellipse (at around 45 degrees)

Comment: @imaluengo Doesn't look like it - if so then it should include the top part of the No Parking sign

Comment: Please post the rest of the code so that we have enough for a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the very least, you need to show us where `x`, `y`, `minor_axis` and `major_axis` come from.

Comment: @ali_m trur, I only had a quick look to the images and it was similar (not exactly after another look).

Comment: @ali_m they simply come from ellipses using fitellipse function.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the images and from the single line of code you posted, the problem is that you are not taking the rotation of the ellipse into account.

`y + (minor_axis / 2)` would only correspond to the top of the cropped region if the minor axis of the ellipse was exactly aligned with the x-axis. However, since your ellipse is rotated by 45 degrees, this is not the case.

You *could* try to work out the bounding box yourself, based on the parametric equations for an ellipse (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/87734/1461210) for an example). A much simpler option is to let OpenCV do the work, and get the bounding box using [`cv2.boundingRect`](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#bounding-rectangle), as Miki mentioned in the comments above.