# Drawing circle with gradient color in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, geometry

How can I draw a circle on an image with gradient colors(something like Gaussian circle) in python using OpenCV?
The circle should have a specific size, (x, y) and color.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829783/draw-a-gradual-change-ellipse-in-skimage/49848093#49848093)?

Comment: If gaussian circle behave like a 2D gaussian, you can just adapt the color of the points inside the circle depending on their distance to the center.