Bounding box of a transformed circle
I'm trying to calculate an axis-aligned bounding box of a circle that is transformed through a 2D affine matrix that can contain any operations (translation, rotation, scale, skew).
I think that good approach would be to transform the circle with the matrix and obtain a rotated ellipse, but I don't know how to do it properly. What I've so far is a code that can calculate a bounding box of a rotated ellipse (not attached) and a code that partially can transform circle to an ellipse (center and radiuses, but ellipse rotation missing):
transformCircle(in matrix, in circle, out ellipse) {
    ellipse.center = matrix * circle.center

    // Calculate conjugated half-diameters
    f1 = matrix * vec2(circle.radius, 0)
    f2 = matrix * vec2(0, circle.radius)
    r = f1.x^2 + f1.y^2 + f2.x^2 + f2.y^2
    s = cross(f1, f2)
    p = sqrt(r + 2*s)
    q = sqrt(r - 2*s)

    ellipse.radiusX = 0.5 * (p + q)
    ellipse.radiusY = 0.5 * (p - q)

    ellipse.rotation = ???;  // Need help here
}


My questions are:

How to calculate ellipse rotation from conjugated half-diameters?
Alternatively how to calculate AABB of circle transformed by a 2D matrix without ellipses, if possible?


Note that in the image you're showing, f1 and f2 are not the radii. They're just projections of two arbitrary vectors that happened to be axis-aligned for the original circle. (they're conjugate diameters, but not radii). Having said that, you probably want to give https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420136/finding-the-major-and-minor-axis-vertices-for-an-ellipse-given-two-conjugate-dia read

Yes, I use them to calculate radii in the code.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Hey, thanks for the link, the angle formula from one of the answers is working great!

Thanks go to @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans for providing the link in the comments with some formulas, one of the answers there contains needed formula for the ellipse rotation.
For future reference and for people searching for this, full pseudo-code that transform a 2D circle into a 2D rotated ellipse by multiplying the circle with an arbitrary 2D affine transformation matrix is this:
transformCircle(in matrix, in circle, out ellipse) {
    ellipse.center = matrix * circle.center

    // Calculate conjugated half-diameters
    f1 = matrix * vec2(circle.radius, 0)
    f2 = matrix * vec2(0, circle.radius)

    f1x2 = f1.x^2
    f1y2 = f1.y^2
    f2x2 = f2.x^2
    f2y2 = f2.y^2;

    r = f1x2 + f1y2 + f2x2 + f2y2
    s = f1.x * f2.y - f1.y * f2.x
    p = sqrt(abs(r + 2*s))
    q = sqrt(abs(r - 2*s))
    t = sqrt(abs(r^2 - 4 * s^2))

    ellipse.radiusX = 0.5 * (p + q)
    ellipse.radiusY = 0.5 * (p - q)

    if (t > 0)
        ellipse.rotation = acos((f1x2 + f2x2 - f1y2 - f2y2) / t) * 0.5
    else
        ellipse.rotation = 0;
}


Note there is no such thing as a "cross product" in 2D, though, so that cross(f1,f2) needs to be something else (or made explicit that it's the z component of a 3D cross product for z=0).

I also did a quick implementation of your pseudo code, and it looks like this gets the rotation angle wrong for two rotation quadrants...

I did some small corrections to avoid division by zero and negative values in square root, anything else I'm missing?

I've also removed the "cross" call and replaced it with the actual formula I'm using

looks like it's still doing fun things depending on the matrix's intrinsic rotation, have a look at https://codepen.io/pomax-the-scripter/pen/KKjvQzK and slide the "angle" around to see it do the right thing half the time, but the wrong thing half the time, too =)

That's interesting and a nice demo! I'm not mathematician, but I think this is related to the fact that the asin function returns values in [-90, 90] degrees range. Interestingly the ellipse rotation is OK.

For an alternative approach, there's also Rytz's construction (I've written up an answer using that, but there's lots of optimization left on the table, the example code is rather verbose mostly for educational purposes =D)

If you have conjugate half-diameters then you probably want to use Rytz's construction to get the major and minor axes:

Given your half diameters with points P and Q on the ellipse with center C, rotate P by 90 degrees over C to form P', and
the midpoint D between P' and Q, and
a circle centered on D passing through C, marking the intersection of the circle with he line through P' and Q as A and B, and
lengths a = |AQ| and b = |BQ|,
your major and minor axes are the vectors v1 from C in the direction of A with length a, and v2 from C in the direction of B with length b.

As an on-page graphics example (but you'll want to click the "full page" link because it's quite wide):


function sourceCode() {
  function draw() {
    clear(`white`);
    const { P, Q } = drawInitialSetup();

    // Let's get to work. Step 1: rotate P to P'
    setColor(`#933`)
    const Pprime = new Point(-P.y, P.x);
    showPointFromCenter(Pprime, `P'`);

    // Step 2: get the midpoint D = Q--P'
    setColor(`#333`)
    const D = new Point((Q.x + Pprime.x) / 2, (Q.y + Pprime.y) / 2);
    showPoint(D, `D`);
    line(Pprime, Q);

    // Then in a "new panel", step 3: get A and B
    translate(width / 3, 0);
    setColor(`red`)
    showPoint(Q, `Q`)
    setColor(`#333`);
    showPointFromCenter(D, `D`)
    noFill();

    setStroke(`#0909`);
    const Dr = dist(C, D)
    circle(D, Dr);

    setColor(`#060`);
    let T = atan2((Q.y - D.y), (Q.x - D.x));
    const A = new Point(D.x + Dr * cos(T), D.y + Dr * sin(T));
    const B = new Point(D.x - Dr * cos(T), D.y - Dr * sin(T));
    showPoint(A, `A`);
    showPoint(B, `B`);

    // step 4: get lengths a and b
    const a = dist(Q, A);
    const b = dist(Q, B);

    // and let's highlight those lengths:
    setStroke(`#2DF`);
    line(B, Q);
    setStroke(`#22D`);
    line(A, Q);

    // step 5: get our ellipse radii!
    const Alen = dist(C, A);
    const Blen = dist(C, B);
    const v1 = new Point(B.x / Blen * a, B.y / Blen * a);
    const v2 = new Point(A.x / Alen * b, A.y / Alen * b);

    // And let's highlight those same identities
    setColor(`#22D`)
    showPointFromCenter(v1, ``);
    setColor(`#2DF`)
    showPointFromCenter(v2, ``);

    setStroke(`#AAA`);
    line(v1, B);
    line(v2, A);

    // Then to finish up, let's show the things we set out to find.
    translate(width / 3, 0);

    // Show the major/minor radius:
    setColor(`black`);
    showPointFromCenter(v1, `v1`);
    showPointFromCenter(v2, `v2`);

    // Show the ellipse's intrinsic rotation:
    setColor(`#9095`);
    const phi = atan2(v2.y, v2.x);
    line(polarPoint(phi, -1000), polarPoint(phi, 1000));

    // and show the AABB (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87734)
    let ux = b * cos(phi);
    let uy = b * sin(phi);
    let vx = a * cos(phi + PI / 2);
    let vy = a * sin(phi + PI / 2);
    let w = sqrt(ux * ux + vx * vx);
    let h = sqrt(uy * uy + vy * vy);

    setColor(`#111`);
    line(-w, -h, w, -h);
    line(-w, h, w, h);
    line(-w, -h, -w, h);
    line(w, -h, w, h);
  }

  // ----------helper code past this point----------

  const C = new Point(0, 0);
  const radius = 100;
  let shearMatrix, scaleMatrix, rotateMatrix;

  function setup() {
    setSize(900, 400);
    setBorder(1, `black`);
    setGrid(20, `grey`);
    addSlider(`sx`, { min: 0, max: 4, value: 1, step: 0.01 });
    addSlider(`sy`, { min: 0, max: 4, value: 1, step: 0.01 });
    addSlider(`shx`, { min: -3, max: 3, value: 1, step: 0.01 });
    addSlider(`shy`, { min: -3, max: 3, value: 0, step: 0.01 });
    addSlider(`angle`, { min: 0, max: TAU, value: 0.3, step: 0.01 });
  }

  function drawInitialSetup() {
    setColor(`black`);
    text(`Panel 1`, 11, 23);
    line(300, 0, 300, height);
    text(`Panel 2`, 311, 23);
    line(600, 0, 600, height);
    text(`Panel 3`, 611, 23);


    // Set up our transforms and draw both our original circle,
    // and the ellipse we get from transforming that circle:
    shearMatrix = [1, shx, shy, 1];
    scaleMatrix = [sx, 0, 0, sy];
    rotateMatrix = [cos(angle), -sin(angle), sin(angle), cos(angle)];
    drawBaseShapes();

    // Show the original "axes" and the corresponding
    // post-transform conjugated half-diameters:
    const P = new Point(...transformCoords(radius, 0));
    const Q = new Point(...transformCoords(0, radius));

    setStroke(`#00F3`);
    line(0, 0, 0, radius);
    line(0, 0, radius, 0);

    setColor(`red`);
    showPointFromCenter(P, `P`);
    showPointFromCenter(Q, `Q`);
    return { P, Q };
  }

  function showPoint(p, label, offset) {
    point(p);
    offsetText(label, p, offset);
  }

  function showPointFromCenter(p, label) {
    line(C, p);
    showPoint(p, label);
  }

  function drawBaseShapes() {
    for (let t = 0, x, y; t <= TAU; t += 0.01) {
      resetTransform();
      translate(width / 6, height / 2);
      x = radius * cos(t);
      y = radius * sin(t);

      setStroke(`#00F3`);

      circle(x, y, 0.05);
      translate(width / 3, 0);
      circle(x, y, 0.05);
      translate(width / 3, 0);
      circle(x, y, 0.05);

      resetTransform();
      translate(width / 6, height / 2);
      let [nx, ny] = transformCoords(x, y);
      setStroke(`red`);
      circle(nx, ny, 0.05);
      translate(width / 3, 0);
      circle(nx, ny, 0.05);
      translate(width / 3, 0);
      circle(nx, ny, 0.05);
    }

    setColor(`red`);
    resetTransform();
    translate(width / 6, height / 2);
    showPoint(C, `C`, -10);
    translate(width / 3, 0);
    showPoint(C, `C`, -10);
    translate(width / 3, 0);
    showPoint(C, `C`, -10);

    resetTransform();
    translate(width / 6, height / 2);
  }

  function polarPoint(a, r) {
    return new Point(r * cos(a), r * sin(a));
  }

  function transformCoords(x, y) {
    return mul(...mul(...mul(x, y, shearMatrix), scaleMatrix), rotateMatrix);
  }

  function mul(x, y, m) {
    return [
      m[0] * x + m[1] * y,
      m[2] * x + m[3] * y,
    ]
  }

  function offsetText(label, p, offset = 20) {
    const a = atan2(p.y, p.x);
    const r = dist(0, 0, p.x, p.y) + offset;
    text(label, r * cos(a) - 5, 5 + r * sin(a));
  }
}

customElements.whenDefined(`graphics-element`).then(() => {
  document.getElementById(`gfx`).loadFromFunction(sourceCode);
});
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/graphics-element@6.2.2/dist/graphics-element.js" async></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/graphics-element@6.2.2/dist/graphics-element.css" async />
<graphics-element id="gfx" title="get ellipse axes"></graphics-element>



As you can see, once we have our major and minor radius, getting the "intrinsic ellipse angle" is simply a matter of using atan2 with the major axis (remembering that atan2 has the signature atan2(y,x), and not atan2(x,y)!) and getting the axis-aligned bounding box ("AABB") is then a matter of plugging the radii and angle into some surprisingly simple math.
